# Setting a length (height or width) for one element minus the variable length of another, i.e. calc(x - y), where y is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I know we can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) when lengths are defined:

```
flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 60px);
left: calc(50% - 25px);
height: calc(100em/5);
```

But what if a length is variable?

```
height: calc(100% - <<header with variable height>>);
```

OR

```
width: calc(100% - 50px - <<box with variable width>>);
```

[image]

Is there a standard way to do this in CSS?

I know the overall task is possible with flexbox and tables, but I'm wondering if CSS offers a simpler method. Flexbox, tables and simple Javascript are acceptable alternatives.

[**height demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f01go4wf/5)

[**width demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f01go4wf/10)

Comment: That's a good question.

Comment: For `width`, table layout might work. Table cell width is automatically calculated by the browser depending on content and sibling elements. I don't have an example ready though. For `height`, I don't think it will.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without JavaScript.

Comment: For anyone who want a non-flex version (and as I said it could be done) and can _survive_ `display: table`, here is one (combined the 2 demo samples into 1) http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/f01go4wf/8/

Comment: For `height`, I usually put an element inside the other, [like here](https://jsfiddle.net/f01go4wf/9/). Hope it help :)

Comment: Great question. One of the few things I really miss from Adobe Flex/AS is the `mx:Spacer` control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use CSS tables:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.horizontal.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent line wrapping */
  border: 1px solid;
}
.left { width: 100px } /* Minimum width of 100px */
.center { width: 0; }  /* Width given by contents */

.vertical.wrapper { height: 200px; }
.vertical.wrapper > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.vertical.wrapper > div > span {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.top    { height: 100px; } /* Minimum heigth of 100px */
.middle { height: 0; }     /* Height given by content */
.bottom { height: 100%; }  /* As tall as possible */
```

```html
<div class="horizontal wrapper">
  <div class="left">100px wide</div>
  <div class="center">Auto width, given by contents</div>
  <div class="right">Remaining space</div>
</div>
<div class="vertical wrapper">
  <div class="top"><span>100px tall</span></div>
  <div class="middle"><span>Auto height, given by contents</span></div>
  <div class="bottom"><span>Remaining space</span></div>
</div>
```

The horizontal case can also be achieved with floats:

```css
#wrapper, .right { overflow: hidden; } /* Establish BFC */
#wrapper > div { border: 1px solid; }
.left, .middle { float: left; }
.left { width: 100px }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">100px</div>
  <div class="middle">Auto width, given by contents</div>
  <div class="right">Remaining space</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Flexbox can do that.

Support is IE10 and up.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f01go4wf/2/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#top {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#bottom {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">green box variable height</div>
  <div id="bottom">blue box no longer overflows browser window</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. Here's 2 examples of some HTML that fill their containers. [Example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jx45a0v2/). [Example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/hf22jw7d/). Once placed in a flexbox they no longer correctly fill their containers. [The workaround is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33119202/128511), the solution involving `position: absolute;`. The solution above leaves the browser in a state that breaks all kinds of content.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm looking for something simple and portable. In the same way a CSS
>   property can be easily applied across documents, I'm looking for
>   something similar in terms of ease-of-application for this function.
>
> ... isolated fix is preferred.

### Horizontal:

This can be achieved using CSS only. As you do not prefer a `flex` layout solution, the next best bet would be a table layout.

A simple CSS snippet which you could drop into your project (and be done with) would look like this:

```
div.flexh {
    display: table; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
div.flexh > div { 
    display: table-cell; width: auto; 
    box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: middle;
}
div.flexh > div:first-child {
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    min-width: 75px; width: 75px; max-width: 75px; 
}
div.flexh > div:last-child { width: 100%; }
```

You can then add your site-specific styling to this base CSS as per site requirements. Like, `nowrap` etc.

Two apparent advantages of this solution are:

1. You do not need to change your markup and also do not need to decorate all children with classes. Just apply the class `flexh` to your parent `div` and that would be it.

*Minimal Markup Required:*

```
<div class="flexh">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

2. You are not limited to just three columns. You could have as many columns as need be. The first one will have fixed width, the last one will be flexible, and all the columns in-between would get content-based widths.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/qqq4mq23/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
div.flexh {
    display: table; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    width: 80%; border: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px dashed black; 
    font-size: 1em;
}
div.flexh > div { 
    display: table-cell; width: auto; 
    box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: middle;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px 5px;
}
div.flexh > div:first-child {
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    min-width: 75px; width: 75px; max-width: 75px; 
    background-color: orange;
}
div.flexh > div:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexh">
    <div>75px Fixed Width</div>
    <div>Variable Content Width</div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Width</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="flexh">
    <div>75px Fixed Width</div>
    <div><img src='//placehold.it/128x48/66c' /></div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Width</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="flexh">
    <div>75px Fixed Width</div>
    <div>Variable TextWidth</div>
    <div>
        <img src='//placehold.it/128x48/66c' />
        <p>Variable ContentWidth</p>
    </div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Width</div>
</div>
```

---

### Vertical:

This is a bit tricky to achieve without `flex` layout. ***A table layout would not work here*** mainly because, the `table-row` would not keep a fixed height as required by your use-case. The `height` on a `table-row` or `table-cell` is only an indicative of the minimum height required. If the space is constrained, or the content exceeds the available space, then the `cell` or `row` will increase its height depending on the content.

As per the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user
>   agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the
>   row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the
>   row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells...
>
> ...the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the
>   content

This effect can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6eropud3/

(*Resize the window pane and you will see that the first row will increase in height as the content cannot be fit into the specified height, hence defeating the purpose*)

Therefore, you can restrict the height indirectly either using inner markup like a div element, or let go of the table-layout and calculate the height for the flexible one. In your use-case, you prefer not to change the markup, hence I am not proposing an inner markup.

The best-bet here would be to use the time-tested model of plain `block`-level `div`s with the height of the flexible one to be calculated. As you have already discovered that it is not possible with CSS, you will need a small JavaScript snippet to do that for you.

A simple JavaScript snippet (*no jQuery*) which you could wrap in a `window.load` and drop into your project (and be done with) would look like this:

```
var flexv = document.querySelectorAll('div.flexv');
/* iterate the instances on your page */    
[].forEach.call(flexv, function(div) {
    var children = [].slice.call(div.children), // get all children
        flexChild = children.splice(-1, 1),     // get the last child
        usedHeight = 0, totalHeight = div.offsetHeight;

    children.forEach(function(elem) {
        usedHeight += elem.offsetHeight; // aggregate the height
    });
    /* assign the calculated height on the last child */
    flexChild[0].style.height = (totalHeight - usedHeight) + 'px';
});
```

The CSS snippet is more or less like the horizontal one, sans table layout, which also you could just drop into your project and just add the additional site-specific styling. Minimal markup required remains the same.

**Demo Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ltcuxdwf/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```js
document.addEventListener("load", flexit);

function flexit(e) {
 var flexv = document.querySelectorAll('div.flexv');
 [].forEach.call(flexv, function(div) {
  var children = [].slice.call(div.children), 
   flexChild = children.splice(-1, 1), 
   usedHeight = 0, totalHeight = div.offsetHeight;
  children.forEach(function(elem) {
   usedHeight += elem.offsetHeight;
  });
  flexChild[0].style.height = (totalHeight - usedHeight) + 'px';
 });
}
```

```css
div.flexv {
    display: inline-table; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    height: 320px; width: 20%; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 1em;
    margin: 8px;
}
div.flexv > div { 
    display: block; height: auto; box-sizing: border-box; 
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
div.flexv > div:first-child {
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    min-height: 36px; height: 36px; max-height: 36px; 
    background-color: orange;
}
div.flexv > div:last-child {
    height: 100%;
    /* Override your custom styling below */
    background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexv">
    <div>36px Fixed Height</div>
    <div>Variable Content Height</div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Height</div>
</div>

<div class="flexv">
    <div>36px Fixed Height</div>
    <div><img src='//placehold.it/64x72/66c' /></div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Height</div>
</div>

<div class="flexv">
    <div>36px Fixed Height</div>
    <div>Variable Text Height</div>
    <div>
        <img src='//placehold.it/72x48/66c' />
        <p>Variable Content Height</p>
    </div>
    <div>Flexible Remaining Height</div>
</div>
```

*Note: As pointed out by @LGSon, the `display: inline-table` used for the demo does not play well with Firefox. This is only for a demo and should be replaced by either `block` or `inline-block` as per your use-case.*

---

Comment: As FF don't like having anything but cells inside a table, the vertical solution doesn't work equally well on it. Is there a way you can compensate that with your script?

Comment: @LGSon: Thank you for the observation. (1) In that case it seems FF is not following the specs. The specs clearly state that anonymous boxes will be generated when table elements are missing. Ref [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#layout-specific-display) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes). (2) In any case, a table-based solution will not work for Op's use-case. The `inline-table` part was a left-over from a previous attempt. It should've been `inline-block` for the demo purpose. Shall fix the answer shortly.

Comment: You're welcome. The FF issue came from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33742866/2827823), which actually used `inline-block`, so they will likely mess up your demo as well (on FF).

Comment: I made both the 2 demos in the question using `display: table`, so how you mean it don't work, as mine obviously does?

Comment: @LGSon: I see only [one demo of yours](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/f01go4wf/8/) and that doesn't have a fixed top section in vertical layout. Do let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for that, it asks for how to adjust the last element in either a vertical or horizontal layout where the preceding element is variable, still I updated my answer with a combined version which has a fixed top section, that actually stays fixed, without script.

Comment: @LGSon: Thank you again for the update. You are doing it by nesting divs as `inline-block` inside of `table-row` and then using `overflow` to control that. Fair enough. As for me, I was simply trying to stick to this requirement of Op - *"I'm looking for a solution that doesn't fundamentally re-structure existing code."*. Let's let the Op decide. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Updated

As I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129660/setting-a-length-height-or-width-for-one-element-minus-the-variable-length-of#comment55192366_33129660) earlier, and besides `flex`, this is also solvable using `display: table` and here is a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/f01go4wf/8/) I made showing that.

If a fixed top also were required for the vertical demo, here is an update of my original `display:table` version: [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/f01go4wf/25/)

Sometimes I haven't been able (or didn't want) to use either flex nor tables, and I have, on and off, looked into making use of [css calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [css attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

Both come short though, as `calc()` can only use `+-*/` and `attr()` can only return a string value, which can't be computed by `calc()`.

My suggestion, using plain javascript, is based on that these 2 methods, at some point, might be extended so we can make better use of them.

This is how I would like see them work;

```
width: calc(100% - attr(this.style.left))
```

but as they don't, and I can't add it to my css either as it wouldn't validate properly (might even break the parsing, who knows) I added a variant as an attribute on the element instead, with some quirks to make it easier to compute.

And in this case (the 2 demos) it looks like this:

```
//height
<div id="bottom" data-calcattr="top,height,calc(100% - toppx)">...</div>

//width 
<div class="box right" data-calcattr="left,width,calc(100% - leftpx)">...</div>
```

Together with below script, which by no means is fully developed/tested on all property combinations, it does adjust the div's size.

In short, when runned, it take the attribute, split it into an array, take the first item value as from which property to read, the second to which property to set and the third to which the read value gets inserted/replaced and assigned to the property to be set (hmmm, still working on a better way to express this, but hopefully the script is clear enough with whats going on).

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zkueot83/2/) showing both the height and width demo, integrated, making use of the same script.

```
function calcattr() {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calcattr]');
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var what = els[i].getAttribute('data-calcattr');
        if (what) {
            what = what.split(',');
            var rect = els[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            var parentrect = els[i].parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
            var brd = window.getComputedStyle(els[i].parentNode,null).getPropertyValue('border-' + what[0] + '-width');            
            what[2] = what[2].replace(what[0],parseInt(rect[what[0]]-parentrect[what[0]]) - parseInt(brd));
            els[i].setAttribute("style", what[1] + ":" + what[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## IN CSS

Although I've never tried it, I believe that this would work:

```
.top {
    height:13px;
}

.main {
    height:calc(100% - var(height));
}
```

http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/why-you-need-use-css-variables-91412904

---

## IN SASS

```
$top_height: 50px

.main {
    height: calc(100% - $top_height)
}
```

[Sass Variable in CSS calc() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function)

Comment: Aren't these 2 samples preprocessors? .. And if so, how will this work when for example the browser resizes? .. Could you please make a working demo.

Comment: @LGSon well for re-sizing purposes you should always use % or em/ex

Comment: I know that, but in this case I can't see it work, and as I'm really interested in all solutions that in one way or the other can solve this, I would like if you could show how you make this work.

Comment: It is not for me to prove your solution works, but yes, I tried and it doesn't work. And the "var" tech is experimental and only works in FF, which make is pretty useless today. I think it is a good idea to really test what you suggest and now that it actually works before adding it as an answer. So again, can you show how you make this work and solve the 2 demos?

Comment: [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) must be prefixed with `--`, e.g. `--height: 13px`, `height: calc(100% - var(--height))`

Answer (score -2):

In both cases on container css you should put:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But, it will hide the information that overflows the container. I think that is the point, since you put `white-space: nowrap;` it means that you don't want to change the height, so you have to hide the text that can't fits the container.