# Restrict height of container inside flex to not grow more then available space on page with css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

EDIT: My example was to complicated. So I made a simpler one.

http://codepen.io/knobo/pen/gaZVoN

.top grows beyond the available size of the html element. I don't want any content outside the current viewport which is 100vh, but I don't know the height of .bottom which can vary.

This line:
      max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
Makes it look like this works. But it does not, because I don't know the height of .bottom, which I just estimated to 60px;

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">Some text</div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x1800">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Could be several lines</button>
  </div>
</div>

html, body {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Css

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px); 
  /* 
  I don't know the height of .bottom 
  It can change when browser is resized too..
  How do I solve this.
  */
}
.left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.bottom {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

EDIT2: (included the original links from the first version)
http://codepen.io/knobo/pen/epboBv  (css version. Does not work)
http://codepen.io/knobo/pen/wKRNjr/ (js version. Works. But I want to know how to do it with css.)

EDIT3
Screenshots:

When browser window is small, the bottom row disappears, when div.right is too big.
[image: Bottom row almost not visible]

When browser window is large everything shows up (corectly)
[image: Everything shows up good]

This is how it should be: div.top is scaled down, and bottom row is stil visible. I was able to do it with javascript. I guess it should be possible with css too.
[image: Corectly scaled]

Comment: The codepen seems to work like you want already.

Comment: The javscript version does what I want. But the css version does not.

Comment: Indeed! What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Now clicking the buttons does nothing, but the layout still works.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the size of .bottom, which I just estimated to 60px here.

Comment: Maybe an answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33129660/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly easy.

```
.right {
   position: relative;
   /* width: Do something with width here. */ 
}

.nooverflow {
   position: absolute;
}
```

then wrap the content of .right with class="nooverflow"

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="overflow">
     {{ Content of .right }}
  </div>
</div>
```