# Div 100% height with display inline

Tags: html, css

I need to have 2 columns of `div`s.

The right column will have a random content which may have 1 line or 100 lines.

The left column I want to follow the height of the right column without javascript.

I am trying this:

```
<div>
   <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%; vertical-align:top; height:100%; background:#FF0000;">
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%; vertical-align:top;">
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
      <div>CONTENT</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the left column is always with height 0px, it should show a red column with the same size as the right column.

So how do I do that using div?

EDIT

Rick Hitchcock's answer is really great but does not work with Firefox. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css)

Comment: There are some good answers here about how to make the div for the left column 100% height. In case it's helpful, note that a similar effect can also be achieved with background colors without having to necessarily make the div 100% height. i.e. you can use a red background for the container div and a white background for the right column.

Comment: Mine does follow your 30% now, and why do you need it to be inline-block?

Comment: BTW if you're going to do these sorts of layouts a lot, you may want to consider a grid framework. 2 favorites of mine are http://materializecss.com/ and http://purecss.io/. Or for some good modern theory if you wanted to do it yourself: http://csswizardry.com/2013/02/responsive-grid-systems-a-solution/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: table` instead.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 60%;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width:30%;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#F00;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width:30%;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#0F0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      LEFT
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update

And if your really need inline-blocks, here I added them inside the table-cell and you can style how you want.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 60%;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width:30%;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#F00;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width:30%;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#0F0;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0ff
}
.right .inner {
  background:#FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="inner">
        LEFT
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="inner">
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code does not work with the 30% width. For some reason the 30% does not work.

Comment: @Samul Now they do and as they are known, you just set the combined width to the wrapper.

Comment: would you mind telling me why did you use 30%? In this case, 50% or any other value would work the same, right? But see, if I need one div to be 30% and the other 70%, how would I do?

Comment: I am an idiot, your answer worked perfectly with 30-70%. Thank you so much, I will not bother you anymore!

Answer (score 2):

Give the containing `div` a table display with 100% width.

Its children will then behave like table cells and grow to match the highest `div` on their row.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%; vertical-align:top; height:100%; background:#FF0000;">

    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%; vertical-align:top;">

        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I wonder if it might make more sense to use `display:table-cell` for the columns rather than `inline-block`, given that you're using `display:table`...

Comment: I really need "display:inline-block" and your answer works perfectly. The other answer is also really good but it does not use inline-block

Comment: @MattBrowne, if you use `table-cell` alone, the 30% width is not accounted for.

Comment: Will not the inner divs become "table-cell" automatically when parent it set to "display:table"?

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock you are a master! Indeed, 30% only works if display is set to inline-block! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LGSon, that's a really good question.  If you inspect the `div`'s in my solution, you'll see that they're still inline-block.  They behave like table cells, but the 30% width is honored, which doesn't happen with `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock one problem, your solution does not work on Firefox. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, @LGSon may have the better answer after all.  Just set the wrapper's width at 60%.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yes, I see they do, though FF obviously wont comply ... and I updated my answer with the 60%.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thank you so much and indeed LGSon works a little better.

Comment: But it still has a flaw: if the left div must be width 30% and the right one 70% of width, how should I do? Rick Hitchcock method works really good on Chrome but not on FF. LGSon works fine on both browsers but 30% and 70% would not work. So how should I do that?

Comment: I am an idiot, your answer worked perfectly with 30-70%. Thank you so much, I will not bother you anymore!

Comment: No problem.  You could also do a flexbox solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/8yLck1at/

Comment: indeed Rick Hitchcock , flexbox is really nice I have never heard of it. If I need something more complicate I will surelly use that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback) article seems to explain the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) method for this pretty well and has a fallback in JS for browsers that don't have flexbox.

I have been using flexbox for awhile with the help of [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) and other mixins with my scss. It seems confusing at first but the first article should help you solve your problem while getting your feet wet in flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  display:table;
} 

.left, .right {
height:100%;
width:50%;
float:left;
display:table-cell;
} 
  
.left { 
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Page Title</title> 
  <style> 
  </style> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class="left"> </div> 
    <div class="right"> 
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1> 
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1> 
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1> 
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <h1>This is a Heading</h1> 
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p> 
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: please check this   
`<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Page Title</title>  
<style>  
html,body{height:100%;display:table;}  
.left,.right{height:100%;width:50%;float:left;display:table-cell;}  
.left{background:red;}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="left">  
</div>  
<div class="right">  
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p><h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p><h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p><h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>  

</body>  
</html>`